# Prototype export - TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

services/user.js

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    amazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

module.exports = function (cognitoUserPool) {

  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

  var UserService = function (cognitoUserPool) {
    this.userPool = new amazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId : cognitoUserPool.user_pool_id,
      ClientId : cognitoUserPool.client_id // App Client id
    });
  }

  UserService.prototype.login = function(email, password) {

      // do stuff
  }

  return UserService;
}
```

routes/user.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    UserService = require('../services/user');

module.exports = function(serverCredentials){

    const router = express.Router();
    const userServiceInstance = new UserService(serverCredentials['cognito-user-pool']);

    router.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;

        if (email && password) {
            userServiceInstance.login(email, password).then(function(result) {
                  // do stuff
            }, function(err) {
                 // do stuff
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Result:

```
TypeError: userServiceInstance.login is not a function
```

Why?

Comment: @ASDFGerte it was just a typo on the formatting whilst editing here

Comment: you have to return instance not function `return new UserService(cognitoUserPool)`

Comment: Just naming wise, this doesn't make much sense. The function imported from `user.js` is a function, which returns `UserService`. You call `UserService = require('../services/user'); const userServiceInstance = new UserService(`, but that's the outer function, which then returns `UserService`. Also, your `cognitoUserPool` is shadowed - the outer function has a parameter with the same name as the inner one. The parameter in `module.exports = function (cognitoUserPool) {` is never used.